# How to avoid Android Webview internal error?

Tags: java, android, native

Installing app on a Samsung Galaxy s7 running Oreo 8.0.0 gives this error and the application crashes when time comes to load the webview. It does not happen on an emulator or on a real device running Nougat 7.0.

```
 I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 67.0.3396.87 (code 339608700)
 I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
 E/linker: normalize_path - invalid input: "null", the input path should be absolute
 W/linker: Warning: unable to normalize "null"
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to GetStringUTFChars
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]     from int android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x74718b58 self=0x75134c0a00
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=23936 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x751860b9c8
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 1079191001 2290269 265 ) utm=99 stm=8 core=7 HZ=100
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0x7fcd24e000-0x7fcd250000 stackSize=8MB
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 0000000000397614  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 000000000045dde8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00000000002d59e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 00000000002d5e60  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+116)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 0000000000108ab0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+148)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 00000000001080e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+832)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 0000000000106a78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+856)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 000000000010fc9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI22GetStringCharsInternalEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jstringPhbb+656)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 000000000000100c  /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so (???)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #09 pc 0000000000f7a56c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_webkit_WebViewFactory_nativeLoadWithRelroFile__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2+284)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(Native method)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.loadNativeLibrary(WebViewFactory.java:705)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:412)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   - locked <0x079dd281> (a java.lang.Object)
 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebStorage.getInstance(WebStorage.java:194)
```

Comment: try adding a Null Pointer exception and handle the No URL there.... or Set all your Strings to some valid url value before you start operating on them

Comment: Did you check for `null` value in your string variable which represents the URL to be loaded into the `WebView`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, strangely enough the check is already present and I'm pretty sure the url is valid since it is hardcoded and lauched on startup. Moreover the only difference causing the crash is upgrading to a device runing Oreo.

Comment: Yup I'm checking the value in: override fun setValue(value: T?) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Value cannot be null")
        }
        super.setValue(value)
    }

Comment: I see a locked object in the log java_vm_ext.cc:504]   - locked <0x079dd281> (a java.lang.Object) maybe this could be some sort of new Oreo security stuff I don't know about?

Comment: url sent to the view is https://google.com

Answer (score 1):

Updated device to latest security patch level: February 1, 2019 solve the problem but don't know why.